# Sharepoint 2019 - published page does not show web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, communication-site

We have just moved to SP2019 - we have an on-premise install.
Just finished the install and are now looking at the new experience within the new site.

I have created a page and have inserted a people web part. I am able to insert, maneuver, customize...all the usual stuff. I have published the page and find that this part does not appear. It is probably something very simple but we do have a lot to discover from the very basic and upward.

Does anyone know why this would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I need to add content to the webpart before publishing it. Part requires content else it stays invisible on the page.